# Unable to update recyclerView using adapter

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to update the below recycler view to show the new data that input from the form in the second activity. However, its only showing the original list that I had in there. What am I doing wrong here?

Here is the main activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    var workoutList = mutableListOf(
        Workout("a","d","d","d"),
        Workout("a","d","d","d"),
        Workout("a","d","d","d")
    )
    val adaptor = WorkoutAdaptor(workoutList)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.btnNext.setOnClickListener {
            Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java).also {
                startActivity(it)
            }
        }

        binding.recyclerView.adapter = adaptor
        binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    }

    override fun onRestart() {
        super.onRestart()

        var workout = intent.getSerializableExtra("EXTRA_WORKOUT") as Workout
        workoutList.add(workout)
        adaptor.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

Here is the adapter:

```
class WorkoutAdaptor (
    var workouts: List<Workout>
    ) : RecyclerView.Adapter<WorkoutAdaptor.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val workoutCardBinding = WorkoutCardBinding.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)

        return ViewHolder(workoutCardBinding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(workouts[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return workouts.size
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(private val workoutCardBinding: WorkoutCardBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(workoutCardBinding.root) {
        fun bind(workout: Workout) {
            workoutCardBinding.tvWorkoutCard.text = workout.toString()
            }
        }
}
```

And here is the activity where I get the workout object from:

```
class SecondActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivitySecondBinding

    lateinit var spWorkoutsPosition: String
    lateinit var spIncrementsPosition: String

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivitySecondBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)


         binding.spWorkoutTypes.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long) {
                spWorkoutsPosition = p0?.getItemAtPosition(p2) as String
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {
            }
        }

        binding.spIncrements.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
             override fun onItemSelected(adapterView: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
                spIncrementsPosition = adapterView?.getItemAtPosition(position) as String
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {
            }
        }

        binding.btnSave.setOnClickListener {
            val workoutName = binding.tvWorkoutName.text.toString()
            val workoutType = spWorkoutsPosition.toString()
            val workoutIncrement = spIncrementsPosition.toString()
            val workoutRestTime = binding.etRestTime.text.toString()
            val workout = Workout(workoutName, workoutType, workoutIncrement, workoutRestTime)
            Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).also {
                it.putExtra("EXTRA_WORKOUT", workout)
                startActivity(it)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OnRestart is called when the Activity has been stopped (onStop) . Showing another activity will lead to onPause -> onResume as far as I know. Check in debug if the method is called if not try onResume. And why do you not launch the second activity with ActivityResultLauncher? Then you could registerForActivityResult and finish() the second activity with a RESULT_OK.

Answer (score 0):

As @John Doe commented you should probably use `ActivityResultLauncher`. refer [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result).

and as for the update issue the recommended way of implementing recyclerView's adapter is `androidx.recyclerview.widget.ListAdapter`. The `ListAdapter` handles addition and removal without the need to redraw the entire view, and even animate those changes.

here's the implementation for your adapter:

```
class WorkoutAdaptor  :
ListAdapter<Workout, WorkoutAdaptor.ItemViewHolder>(DiffCallback()) {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ItemViewHolder {
    return ItemViewHolder(
        ItemAutocompleteSearchResultBinding.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
            parent,
            false
        )
    )
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bind(position)
}

inner class ItemViewHolder(val binding: ItemAutocompleteSearchResultBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    fun bind(position: Int) {
        binding.apply {
            workoutCardBinding.tvWorkoutCard.text = getItem(position).toString()
        }
    }
}

private class DiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Workout>() {
    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Workout, newItem: Workout): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }

    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Workout, newItem: Workout): Boolean {
        return oldItem.param1 == newItem.param1 &&
                oldItem.param2 == newItem.param2 &&
                oldItem.param3 == newItem.param3 &&
                oldItem.param4 == newItem.param4
    }
}
```

}

then you only have to call,

```
adapter.submitList(workoutList)
```

after you update the workoutList and the `ListAdapter` handles the rest.
and also call the `adapter.submitList()` in `onStart()` or `onResume()` methods.